# Retrieve data with some filters in Spring Data JPA

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning spring data jpa and I have two tables name `TBL_PLAYER` and `TBL_TEAM`. Also note that these are already existing tables in the database. What i want is to retrieve data players detail of current teams. I can successfully achieve it from using following native query.

```
SELECT TBL_PLAYER.ID,
       TBL_PLAYER.NAME, 
       TBL_PLAYER.AGE, 
       TBL_PLAYER.TEAM_ID, 
       TBL_PLAYER.INCOME,  
FROM   TBL_PLAYER, TBL_TEAM
WHERE  (TBL_PLAYER.TEAM_ID = TBL_TEAM.TEAM_ID)
```

And here are current view of data tables

**TBL_PLAYER**

```
| ID | NAME | AGE | TEAM_ID | INCOME |
  1    John   23       1       1000
  2    Ann    24       2       3000
  3    Sam    45       5       9000
  4    Nick   18       1       5000
```

**TBL_TEAM**

```
| TEAM_ID | WINS |
     1       10
     5       60
```

Please also find my java code snippets as well.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PLAYER")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private int name;
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team teamId;
    @Column(name = "INCOME")
    private int income;

    //setter and getters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_TEAM")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private int teamId;
    @Column(name = "WINS")
    private int wins;

    //setter and getters
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Player, Long> {

}
```

When i use `repository.findAll()` it gives me `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`. Then i have tried with `FetchType.LAZY` and it returned all the data rows which is not what i am looking for.

What i'm doing wrong here or is what i'm trying possible thing in spring data jpa.

Any help would be grateful..

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following solution. I have used supported keywords inside method names as in [spring data jpa documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference).

I have added following code which did the trick for me.

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Player, Long> {
        
    public long countByTeamIdIn(Collection<Team> teams);
    
    public List<Player> findByTeamIdIn(Collection<Team> teams);
}
```

Then used `repository.findByTeamIdIn(teams)`.